# Rename a folder via HTML POST request

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, customization, theme-development

I am trying to rename a folder in the uploads folder if an HTML form is submitted (used to edit entry names).

This following code is what I have so far but it isn't working.

```php
if(isset($_POST['Edit_Client']) == '1')

{

rename("/wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name/", "/wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$New_Name/");

}
```

I have tried changing the file permissions to 777 for the whole path, but that didn't work.

I tried to require once wp-config and wp-settings but that didn't work either

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use full file/directory name, e.g. `rename( ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name", ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$New_Name" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to rename you have to alter your code like bellow. You code was missing absolute path of the directory. That's why your code was not working. Adding `ABSPATH` will fix the code.

```
rename( ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name", ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$New_Name" );
```

Why not you use `WP_Filesystem_Direct`. It's better and fatal-safe. You can easily use that by including these to file to your `functions.php`

```
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php');
```

Now from you given code, alter that like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Edit_Client']) == '1'){
    $current = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name";
    $destination = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$New_Name";

    WP_Filesystem_Direct::move($current,$destination);
}
```

`WP_Filesystem_Direct` will automatically check whatever approach will be better. It will try to rename first. If fails then It will make a copy and delete old folder.

Read more about [WP_Filesystem_Direct::move](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_direct/move/) & [WP_Filesystem_Direct](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_direct/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I tried adding the two required files and using the Direct::move but it didn't work with me (perhaps it has to do with my backend settings?

However, I used the following and it worked:

if(isset($_POST['Edit_Client']) == '1')

{

$current = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name";

$destination = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$New_Name";

rename($current,$destination);

}

What is the risk of fatal error occuring if a file is renamed in a certain format? I guess a file named with a PHP extension?

Comment: Error could be happened because of permission issue.

Comment: I have all my folder permissions towards the end path set at 777, is there other potential to block it?

Comment: Btw what is the potentially fatal risk?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to mention how to Rename first, and then mentioning fatal error and suggesting to use the WP_Filesystem::move, I will accept it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: updated the code.